# How to sum an ArrayList in Java element by element

Tags: java, arraylist, sum

I have a double ArrayList that has this numbers:

2, 4, 10, 14, 20, 33...

And I want to create a new ArrayList with the sum of the first ArrayList, but the sum result must to be:

2, 6, 16, 30, 50, 83...

The operations inside must to be:

position 0: 2 without operations

position 1: 2 + 4 = 6

position 2: 10 + 6 = 16

position 3: 14 + 16 = 30

position 4: 20 + 30 =  50

position 5: 33 + 50 = 83

...

At the moment i have this:

```
   ArrayList <Double> velocidad = new ArrayList();
   ArrayList <Double> velocidad_acum = new ArrayList();
   double prevVel = 0;
   double vel_acum = 0;

   velocidad.add(vel);

for (double i : velocidad){
    int currentIndex = velocidad.indexOf(i);
    int prevIndex = velocidad.indexOf(i) - 1;
    if (currentIndex > 0){
        prevVel = velocidad.get(prevIndex);
        vel_acum = prevVel + i;
    }
}        
velocidad_acum.add(vel_acum);
```

"vel" is a variable that update its value each second, and each second the ArrayList "velocidad" acumulates a new number inside.

This code mades with the example above:

2, 6, 14, 24, 34, 53...

position 0: 2 without operations

position 1: 2 + 4 = 6

position 2: 10 + 4 = 14

position 3: 14 + 10 = 24

position 4: 20 + 14 =  34

position 5: 20 + 33 = 53

...

Comment: First you need to write some code

Comment: If I am reading this correctly, is your question is how to write a for loop?

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Double> one = Arrays.asList(2.0, 4.0, 10.0, 14.0, 20.0, 33.0);
List<Double> two = new ArrayList<>();

double sum = 0;
for (double d: one) {
    sum += d;
    two.add(sum);
}

System.out.println(two);
// [2.0, 6.0, 16.0, 30.0, 50.0, 83.0]
```

Start `sum` with `0` and keep adding intermediate `sum` values to the `List`.

Comment: Don't do people's homework for them. They learn nothing if they can't do basic operations.

Answer (score -1):

We're not going to do your homework for you, but here is a basic pseudo code solution:

```
public static List<Double> sum(List<Double> src) {
    //Create a List<> to hold your sums
    List<Double> sumList = new ArrayList<>();
    //loop through your src list
    for (Double item : src) {
        //If the sumList is empty, add the item to your sumList
        //other wise, grab the value at the end of your sumList
        //add it to the item, and add that value to your sumList
    }
    return sumList;
}
```